# Owl Image Carousel - Flickering buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I have created a basic image carousel using the Owl Carousel plugin.

By default, the "prev" and "next" buttons appear below the images, I have used a negative margin in CSS to push them up over the image.

However, now, when I hover over the buttons, they start to flicker. Has anyone else come across this? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: please provide a JSfiddle, or code to make things clear. (btw try `z-index: 999;` on the buttons)

Comment: please show your code

Comment: z-index:999; didn't work on the buttons. how could I make a JSfiddle when I used a plugin with multiple CSS files?

Comment: try this

owl-wrapper's z-index smaller than owl-pagination's z-index

Answer (score 1):

Set the z-index higher for buttons than slide div and put backface-visibility:hidden; on button and slide both.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the buttons from flickering, simply set the ".owl-wrapper" to have a lower z-index than ".owl-pagination".

Thanks for solving this so quickly.